# Can you use checkpoints for the no-hit achievments?

Tags: everhood

The title is the majority of the question. For the battles that have checkpoints, can I use them to complete the achievements that require you beating them without getting hit?

Such as, can I do the beginning to the first checkpoint without getting hit, then can I then get hit after the checkpoint and restart from it and keep trying until I get that part done without getting hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [update 1.0.29](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1229380/view/3060737864933565543), checkpoints can no longer be used to complete No-Hit achievements. This includes "Cutscene" checkpoints (in the spoiler below there is an example of a battle with a cutscene).

> An example of a battle with a cutscene is the battle titled Post Mortem, which happens right after the Incinerator sequences assuming you do not survive it. You must go through the "cutscene" that shows up before the fight starts if you want to unlock the achievement for the battle.

<strike>I decided to test it myself. You can indeed earn achievements while using checkpoints. I tested this out on two battles, and earned their respective achievements while using checkpoints.</strike>

I would go until I got a no-hit run of the beginning to the first checkpoint, and then keep trying first checkpoint to second checkpoint/end.